# How to separate each rectangle tiles and crop it from below image of video conferencing?

Tags: python, opencv

[The image has 4 streams, how do we crop each stream, Disclaimer: The number of streams could be 4, 8, 16, 32](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONvo1.jpg)

I have tried to develop an algorithm with the below steps.

- Get horizontal and vertical lines
- Draw on the line.
- Find rectangle tiles using the find contours method from OpenCV
- Crop each stream and save it into a different file.

But this approach does not hold true for a random number of streams.

Let me know your inputs on this.

```
   import cv2


# Load image, convert to grayscale, Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread(r'C:\oldLaptopData\PF_2021\iotG_work\test_black\MSBlack.jpg')
#image = cv2.imread(r"C:\oldLaptopData\PF_2021\iotG_data\video_samples\split_frames\out1.jpg")
result = image.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Detect horizontal lines
horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (200, 1))
detect_horizontal = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, horizontal_kernel, iterations=2)
cnts = cv2.findContours(detect_horizontal, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
print(len(cnts))
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(result, [c], -1, (36,255,12), 10)

# Detect vertical lines
vertical_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1, 200))
detect_vertical = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, vertical_kernel, iterations=2)
cnts = cv2.findContours(detect_vertical, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(result, [c], -1, (36,255,12), 10)

cv2.imwrite('result.jpg', result)
```

Comment: is this always a grid, or can they be tiled in different ways? run a sobel in x and y direction. calculate row and column sums of the *absolute values* of the sobel data. you get curves. plot them. you'll see peaks

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, ok I will try this sobel approach. It will be changed if the number of streams is 3 or 5 or odd numbers,